# How do i make the conversion from string to char

Tags: c#

What do I need to change to make the conversion from string to char? Why do I get this error?

"Cannot convert expression of type string to type char"

```
        int a, b;
        char op;
        Console.WriteLine("Dati primul numar:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Dati al doilea numar:");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        op = (char)Console.Read();
        switch (op )
        {
            case "+" : Console.WriteLine("ADUNARE:{0}+{1}={2}",a,b,a+b);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use  `case '+'` instead of  `case "+"` by the way `Console.Read` method returns an integer.and you will get the ascii value of the `char`.If you want to read one character, use `op = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
op = Console.Read().ToCharArray()[0];
```

Converts the string from Read function to char array and uses it's first character to set `op`